# APEX Dynamic Actions Sample App - Not sending session state back, but working

Tags: oracle, apex

There is a sample app for Dynamic Actions you can install, I am using APEX 23.1.

There is an example of making selections in a Shuttle and having an interactive grid refresh automatically when changes are made to the Shuttle.

There is no submit, and no other mechanism in the Dynamic Action to send the shuttle selection back into session state.  So I have zero idea how it is working.

When I try to recreate the example, I have to add a PL\SQL step into the Dynamic Action, with an expression of NULL, just so I can send the values back into session state.

Screenshots

**UI**

[image: Example App UI:]

**Simple Refresh action on Shuttle Dynamic Action**

[image: Simple dynamic action to refresh the interactive grid region]

**SQL on Interactive Grid**

[image: Interactive Grid SQL]

**Only way I can get it working in my app**

Here I manually submit the value of the page item to session set before doing the IG refresh.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could be forgetting this setting here in your interactive grid, which refreshes the region:

[image]

You need to add your Shuttle page item under *Page Items to Submit*.

Comment: Ah, thanks.  Never use that.  So that submits that item whenever the IG gets called to be refreshed?

Comment: I was trying it with and without and playing with the Session attribute of the page item, but I know for sure the grid would not update without the above